# Correcting the imported latin1 data to be utf8

Tags: mysql-5, restore, character-set

I restored my drupal site database from a backup but after i finished i discovered that the Imported data was symbols like this `Ù‚ÙˆØ§Ù†ÙŠÙ† ÙƒØ±Ø©` because the backup was taken using latin1 charset but my tables and database are utf8

I want a way to convert this data to utf8 so the are stored as letters and words in my database not symbols

How can i do this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can restore your database using this command

```
mysql -u someuser -p --default-character-set=utf8 somedatabase < backup.sql
```

This overrides the default client character set.

I would also make sure that my tables are also in utf8.

So when you open up your backup file with a text editor, you should see **utf8** as the **DEFAULT CHARSET**

```
CREATE TABLE `sometable` (
  `c1` varchar(10) NOT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

If you are still having problems, check your backup and make sure that the actual data being restored is correctly formatted.  If you had a character like é for example, it should show up as **é** when you view it in a text editor and not as `&eacute;` or some unreadable symbol.

One additional note.  utf8_general_ci and latin1_swedish_ci are collations and not character sets.   Character sets like UTF8 can have multiple collations, some are case sensitive _cs and others are case insensitive _ci.  Collations set rules for character comparison and sorting.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collation

Comment: i tried this but the data still stored as symbols and the data in the file are symbols too, is there any other solution to this?

Comment: What if for the mysqldump command you also use the same option  --default-character-set=charset ?  So mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -p mydatabase

Comment: mysqldump didn't work it didn't complete the database back file execution

Comment: I ran the command like this and didn't run into any errors.  Can you post the error you received?  mysqldump --default-character-set=utf8 -u root -p mydatabase > /tmp/mydatabase.sql

Comment: I used the mysql command again with an old backup and every thing went fine thank you for your help

Comment: Cool, glad to be of help